# Twitter Card Preview is failing with twitter:image

Tags: 7, meta-tags, social-network

I'm trying to add Twitter Cards to my site so that tweets referencing my blog posts will be expandable and show extra info. I've installed the [metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module, enabled the Metatag: Twitter Cards sub-module as well as patched the Twitter Cards sub-module to fix a problem with it generating `<link />` tags instead of `<meta />` tags.

When I include a twitter:image tag, the Twitter Card fails, but when I remove it, it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
<meta property="twitter:url" content="http://liberalgeek.com/content/why-do-atheists-celebrate-christmas" />
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta property="twitter:description" content="I can&#039;t speak for all atheists, I can only speak for myself, so please leave a comment below and explain why you celebrate Christmas! When I hear someone ask, &quot;Why do atheists celebrate Christmas?&quot; my first thought often is: Better Question: Why do Christians celebrate Christmas?" />
<meta property="twitter:creator" content="@kennywyland" />
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Why do Atheists celebrate Christmas?" />

<!-- the following line causes the problem -->
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://liberalgeek.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Christmas%20Tree.jpg" />
```

I have tried `<meta property=` as well as `<meta name=` and they behave the same way.

The image is publicly visible, it's large enough without being too large... what is wrong?

To be clearer, by "failing" I mean that Twitter refuses to acknowledge there is a Twitter Card for that URL, so the preview is not shown along with the tweet. When I test this on the twitter card preview page, this is the result I get:

[image]

However, when I remove the `twitter:image` tag and generate the preview again it works just fine and looks like this:

[image]

During further testing I found the STRANGEST thing. If I change the domain from liberalgeek.com to www.liberalgeek.com, the Twitter Card successfully generates, although the thumbnail image is a broken image. (That may just be due to high twitter volume, but I'm not sure.)

[image]

I want the Twitter card to work, even if they don't include the unnecessary www.

Notice that:

- The .htaccess file is the standard one installed with Drupal
- I don't think I'm using gzip compression
- Apache isn't sending back the wrong headers
- The error log doesn't shown any error
- The access log shows entries with a return code equal to 200, and a correct content length value, when Twitter tries to access the image

I found a site on my server which twitter handles just fine:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://www.geekqi.com/images/StylizedYinYangRedLucida.png" />
```

But I'm not sure what the difference is between this and all of my other sites.

Comment: what do you mean with "fails"? do you see a broken image?

Comment: Added an image to show you what I mean about "failing."

Comment: did you try to change from "property" to "name"? see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards

Comment: Yes, but the result is the same.

Comment: have you checked error log ? Is there any error ?

Comment: from `dev.twitter.com/docs/cards` - `URL to a unique image representing the content of the page. Do not use a generic image such as your website logo, author photo, or other image that spans multiple pages` are you sure your image not spans multiple pages?

Comment: I noticed that if I try to access the image folder in your website I get the following error:`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in image_style_deliver() (line 825 of /home/kwyland/domains/liberalgeek.com/html/modules/image/image.module).`. Are you using any custom image-related modules? because it could be causing a conflict with image.module. And could you try creating a new folder manually under sites/default/files and upload the preview image manually to that folder and test its url?

Comment: @neok Yes, this image only exists on this one page.

Comment: @AhmedJabar I'm not using any custom image modules and it doesn't really matter that the directory url doesn't provide usable data, because the url to the image provides perfectly usable data. That's standard drupal behavior.

Comment: @mohit_rocks, I've checked the error logs, there are no errors. I've watched the access logs as well to see what happens when Twitter fetches the image and the log shows a 200 success code with an appropriately sized response.

Comment: Kenny, it's definitely some type of server issue.  None of your images work including images on your "In a day development site." This functionality works out of the box with drupal if you meet the standard requirements for twitter:cards, so you might want to direct your attention to your server setup.  Possibly create a test installation on another server to troubleshoot.

Comment: @jsheffers, the In A Day Development site is also drupal, so I tried a non-drupal site (still on the same server) and those images didn't work either, but it appears ANY image served that isn't on my server seems to work... so you're right. This has got to be a server issue, maybe something in the apache config, but I can't imagine what would cause that. I might have to take this to the Apache Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't get it though, I just scp'd the image to another server on a different machine (one that I verified Twitter is happy with) and I curl'd the image from my server and the other server and they are delivered bit for bit the same.

Comment: I just found a site on my server that serves the images perfectly fine for twitter... so it doesn't look like it's a server-wide configuration problem. This image works: http://www.geekqi.com/images/StylizedYinYangRedLucida.png

Comment: Your code works for me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a test with this values

```
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://liberalgeek.com/content/why-do-atheists-celebrate-christmas" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@kennywyland" />
<meta property="twitter:description" content="I can&#039;t speak for all atheists, I can only speak for myself, so please leave a comment below and explain why you celebrate Christmas! When I hear someone ask, &quot;Why do atheists celebrate Christmas?&quot; my first thought often is: Better Question: Why do Christians celebrate Christmas?" />

<meta name="twitter:title" content="Why do Atheists celebrate Christmas?" />

<!-- the following line causes the problem -->
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg">
```

Changing the image, the card works normally in the preview tool.
I would try to check if you have some restriction on the file.
Have a look at the [crawling section](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards#crawling) of the API docs

> Twitter's crawler will respect robots.txt when scanning URLs. If a
>   page with card markup is blocked, no card will be shown. If an image
>   URL is blocked, no thumbnail or photo will be shown.

**UPDATE**
As suggested by the author of the question, changing robot.txt could not be enough. Since Twitter could have cached your file, you need to wait at least 24 hours to let it expires.
I add that the same problem could be found not just on robot.txt file, but also on images. Indeed, wrong Twitter cache could lead to a 404 error and a broken preview image.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue do the following:
**For twitter** go to https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator and insert the webpage URL and then hit Preview card, this will clear twitter cache.

**For facebook** go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ and insert the webpage URL (make sure Sharing Debuger tab is active)and hit Debug, this will clear your cache. If you still see the old image Scarp the URL by pressing **Scrap Again** button.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the Twitter API balks on the %20 space in the image filename.

To eliminate that possibility, it's worth testing with an image URL that has no space in the filename,

i.e:

```html
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://liberalgeek.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Christmas-Tree.jpg" />
```

vs the current:

```html
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://liberalgeek.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Christmas%20Tree.jpg" />
```

Comment: I had that thought as well and tested it with http://www.liberalgeek.com/sites/default/files/styles/twitter_card/public/Martin-Luther-King-Right-to-Work.jpg, but no. That's not the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://liberalgeek.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Christmas%20Tree.jpg" />`

Comment: Could you maybe add some explanation to your code?